# ALTER TABLE using WHERE clause condition

Tags: sql

I was under the assumption that they was a WHERE Clause for ALTER and I have understood now after some research that WHERE Clause doesn't exist for ALTER Command. How to handle cases where we might need to check some conditions in the ALTER Command?

this is my query , what's im doing wrong please ?

```
ALTER TABLE cp_asset_translations CHANGE caption caption VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT NULL WHERE LENGTH(caption) > 255;
```

Comment: Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products, and MariaDB is a fork of MySQL.

Comment: First you cannot have one column with different structure depending upon the content of that column

Answer (score 2):

There is no `WHERE`.  And there is no ability to change the length of a column in some rows but not others.  But that is not a problem.  You can change the length of the caption to `VARCHAR(1000)` and because the string is variable length, no additional space is used for shorter strings:

```
ALTER TABLE cp_asset_translations CHANGE caption caption VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Note:  I assume that this `ALTER TABLE` is valid in the database you are using.  The statement varies significantly across databases.